# Passing in arguments to gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a task to run jshint:

```
gulp.task('lint-scripts', function () {
    var jshint = buildTools.jshint,
        filesToLint = ...

    return gulp
        .src(filesToLint)
        .pipe(jshint('jshint.json'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        //.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
    ;
});
```

This is how it should perform during development.

I also need a "release" version of this same task, where this line isn't commented out:

```
//.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
```

What's the best way to do this? I don't want to create to duplicate tasks with one line of code difference. Is there a way I can pass in a variable to the task `lint-scripts` and the `fail` reporter will optionally be used?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really simple example where you can use [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util) and [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) libraries to pass parameters when you start your script this way `gulp [taskname] [--settingName settingValue]`. For example:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  gulpUtil = require("gulp-util"),
  gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

// Constants
var GULP_CMD_SETTING_A = "A",
  GULP_CMD_SETTING_B = "B";

// Setting to be used in tasks
var jsSetting = GULP_CMD_SETTING_A; // Default value

// Init task for setting
gulp.task("cmd-settings", function (done) {

  if (gulpUtil.env.settingName === GULP_CMD_SETTING_A) {
    // ... logic
    jsSetting = GULP_CMD_SETTING_A;
  } else if (gulpUtil.env.settingName === GULP_CMD_PARAM_B) {
    // ... logic
    jsSetting = GULP_CMD_PARAM_B;
  }

  done();

});
```

This is a base task being required by the tasks needing `jsSetting` to use it to know what behavior to execute.

Afterwards in all tasks that need `jsSetting`, just make sure to put the `"cmd-settings"` task as prerequired. Example of how to use `jsSetting`:

```
gulp.task("use-cmd-settings", ["cmd-settings"], function () {
  return gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(gulpIf(jsSetting === GULP_CMD_SETTING_A, jshint.reporter(...))
    .pipe(gulpIf(jsSetting === GULP_CMD_SETTING_B, concat())
    .pipe(...);
}
```

All I have to do is `gulp use-cmd-settings --settingName A` and you have a task that lints your code, and `gulp use-cmd-settings --settingName B` you have a task that concats your code (this is just an example, not having much real life usefulness) :)

## EDIT:

You can also use the setting from the command to define the same task names but differently or load one of two different files with the same tasks.

```
if (gulpUtil.env.settingName === GULP_CMD_SETTING_A) {
  // ... logic
  jsSetting = GULP_CMD_SETTING_A;
} else if (gulpUtil.env.settingName === GULP_CMD_PARAM_B) {
  // ... logic
  jsSetting = GULP_CMD_PARAM_B;
}

if (jsSetting === GULP_CMD_SETTING_A) {
  // Tasks definition or import from file
} else if (jsSetting === GULP_CMD_SETTING_B) {
  // Tasks definition or import from other file
}
```

This is extremely helpful when you have a truck load of gulp tasks and you want to split them in files. Two files have the same tasks (in regards to responsibilities) but one is for development and one is for production let's say.

Hope it helped!